# SSIS - Best way to insert large number of rows (hundred millions of rows)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, ssis

So here's the scenario: I have an XML file, which is in size of 500GB, and with data of around 600 million rows (once on a database table). I'm using SSIS for the operation, and since it consumes a REALLY large amount of memory if I am to use an SSIS component (i.e.: `XML Source`), it might cause a timeout (correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I know, using the components on SSIS loads the content of the XML into memory - with a file that big it will surely cause errors). My approach then is:

- Use a `Script Task` to parse the XML data using XML Reader (XML Reader by far is the best approach, since it parses the XML on a forward, non-cached approach)
- Insert the data on a `DataTable`
- Every 500,000 rows on the `DataTable`, insert the contents to the database using `SqlBulkCopy`, then clear the contents of the `DataTable`

My problem is, currently, I tried it to parse another file with the size of 200GB, and it's running on around 13.5M / 1 hour - and I don't know if it's still fine with that run time. It sure solves my problem - but it's not too elegant, I mean, there should be other ways.

I'm looking on other approaches, like:

- Dividing the large XML files into small pieces of CSVs (around 20GB) then use an SSIS `Data Flow task`
- Use `INSERT` script every new rows

Can you help me do decide which is best? Or suggest any other solutions.

Every answer will be very much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention - my approach will be dynamic. I mean, there are many tables that will be populated with large sized XML files. So, using a Script Component as source might be not so useful, since I still need to define the output columns. But still, will give it a try.

***EDIT 2015-07-28***

The file is from our client, and we can't do anything on what source they want to send to us. XML, that's it. Here is a sample from the XML I am consuming:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MFADISDCP>
  <ROW>
    <INVESTMENT_CODE>DATA</INVESTMENT_CODE>
    <DATE_OF_RECORD>DATA</DATE_OF_RECORD>
    <CAPITAL_GAIN_DISTR_RATE>DATA</CAPITAL_GAIN_DISTR_RATE>
    <INCOME_DISTR_RATE>DATA</INCOME_DISTR_RATE>
    <DISTR_PAYMENT_DATE>DATA</DISTR_PAYMENT_DATE>
    <CURRENCY>DATA</CURRENCY>
    <CONFIRM>DATA</CONFIRM>
    <EXPECTED_DISTRIBUTION_AMOUNT>DATA</EXPECTED_DISTRIBUTION_AMOUNT>
    <KEYING_STATUS>DATA</KEYING_STATUS>
    <DAF_RATE>DATA</DAF_RATE>
    <INCOME_START_DATE>DATA</INCOME_START_DATE>
    <ALLOCABLE_END_DATE>DATA</ALLOCABLE_END_DATE>
    <TRADE_DATE>DATA</TRADE_DATE>
    <OVR_CAPITAL_GAIN_DISTR_OPTION>DATA</OVR_CAPITAL_GAIN_DISTR_OPTION>
    <OVR_INCOME_DISTR_OPTION>DATA</OVR_INCOME_DISTR_OPTION>
    <BACKDATED_DISTRIBUTION>DATA</BACKDATED_DISTRIBUTION>
    <DATE_MODIFIED>DATA</DATE_MODIFIED>
  </ROW>
<!--AROUND 49M+ OF THIS ROWS-->
</MFADISDCP>
```

Comment: You could have a single data flow task with a script component that just streams the data straight out into a bulk load destination with batch size 500,000.

Comment: @MartinSmith - please see my update on the question.

Comment: Work out the bottleneck. It's most likely your XML shredder but it could be... network, memory, disk, contention in the database (do you have exclusive locks?). Does the source have to be XML? I suggest for example that you pre shred into a CSV then upload that and you probably find that XML>CSV takes far longer than CSV>Database

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - sadly, yes, the source should be XML. we considered  having it on a CSV, but we're not sure whether to take this approach since the processes will double: XML to CSV, CSV to staging table, staging table to data warehouse. right now we have it as XML to staging then staging to data warehouse. right now, i tested this approach on a 100 GB file, with around 49M rows, and it took around 3 hours to populate it on the staging table. i'm not sure if the run time is good or not.

Comment: Until you split the XML shredding from the table load and analyse performance seperately you can't decide on what needs optimising. So start there.

Comment: When thinking about storing data in a file, consider the overhead of your storage structure. The skinniest XML is going to cost 7 bytes of storage for every element you have. A few hundred rows, hell, a few hundred thousand rows and that sin isn't horrific. Half a billion rows though is untenable. Depending on what's being stored, you could be spending a quarter to half of your storage cost on the structure alone. Maybe you don't care about the storage cost but there is also the read access cost. If can reduce my IOPS from 500GB to 375GB, my time to read to EOF goes from ~3hrs to 2.2 @ 50MB/s

Comment: Contrast that with using a single delimiter that's 1 byte per element. That may not sound like much but at scale, you bet your butt you're going to wish you had sized your storage container appropriately. Or you'll make some hardware vendor's day.

Comment: All of that said, SSIS is not the tool for *generic* data parser. It is, in the sense that it handles most any source inputs but it'd not DTS. The primary mechanism for moving data in SSIS is the Data Flow Task. The DFT does not handle changing data signatures. They are set at the time of package creation and cannot change. The upside of this design approach is the performance of a DFT kicks the pants out of a classic DTS package. The downside in your situation is that you're going to write a C# app within an SSIS package. Very little gain at great expense.

Comment: @billinkc- we considered storing it in a file because of the reason you mentioned - storage structure. right now the approach is using a script task with the xml reader and sql bulk copy on the SSIS package. i tested just reading a file, a 100 GB file with 52 columns and 49M+ rows is read at around 10mins. having it inserted on the database table consumes around 3 hrs of runtime. it really runs fine, the problem is that we're not sure if this runtime is fine.

Comment: @billinkc - we also tested it on a data flow task, same file, and it consumes around 2 hrs 50 mins of runtime. we're eyeing that maybe a data flow task might suffice, but we're not sure if it will timeout on a 500GB file. the 500GB file contains around 600M rows, and as far as i know, a Xml Source component of DFT loads the content on memory, since its nature is the same as using XmlDocument class.

Comment: You can see many reasons here to not store the source as XML. It's not clear if it is an option to change it. Can you clarify? Particularly when you say the file has 52 columns and 49M+ rows... that's tabular data. There is no point in storing tabular data in XML (a verbose tree format). If you must store in a fancy format, JSON is a tree structure and require less characters to store. Again I suggest you time the XML shredder (the script task, but feeding nothing) and see how long that part takes. Again I ask:why is XML necessary? Is you source data in a heirarchical format?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - please see my edit regarding on the source file. for the time consumed on Script Task to read the data, it takes around 7mins for a 100GB file.

Comment: So the next question is: If you load an equivalent CSV into your table how long does it take? If it takes appreciably less than 7 minutes then your XML parser is a bottleneck (for this data sample). i.e. your insert destination spends all it's time waiting for data rather than inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this then I would break it down into the following tasks:

1. Convert XML file into a (tab or comma) delimited file. If your server has fast disks (SSD) then this should be very quick. Be careful of strings in your data that may contain special characters that may break the delimiter format. Don't use the `DataTable` object as it is slow. You could stream this so that you don't need to have the whole file in memory at one go (unless your server has several hundred gigs of memory)
2. Truncate the stage table in your database that you will use to load the data into.
3. Use SQL Server's `bcp.exe` to push the delimited file into a stage table on your database. This is probably the fastest way to get a large amount of data into a database. A problem with this is that if it fails then it is very hard to find which row of data caused the failure.
4. Delete the delimited file as you don't need them lying around taking up lots of space.
5. Create a SQL stored procedure to move the data from the stage table to wherever you will be using it.

You could use SSIS script tasks for this or you could write your own stand alone services.

Note, this is all theoretical, there may be better ways of doing it but this may be a good starting point and to find out where your bottlenecks are.